# Filecopy with no permission

Tags: vba, ms-access

Hello I would like to be able to copy an excel file into a folder without having the permissions.

```
Sub CopyFile()
Dim Folder As String, FileSource As String, FileTarget As String
Folder = "W:\BusIntegration\" & "\"
FileSource = Folder & "excel.xlsx"
FileTarget = "W:\branch\excel.xlsx"
FileCopy FileSource, FileTarget
End Sub
```

W:\branch asks to have permission to access it.

Thanks for the help

Comment: You can't do this. You need permission, either if you copy manually or programmatically.

Comment: Can you explain more about this use case?  There may be solutions but they would depend on exactly what it is you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Permission denied errors are usually a case of either the file path is wrong or the file is in use or in a locked state.

Looking at your code the `Folder` variable might be causing the error due to the double `\`

```
Folder = "W:\BusIntegration\" & "\"
FileSource = Folder & "excel.xlsx"

'This will return "W:\BusIntegration\\excel.xlsx"
```

Instead try

```
Folder = "W:\BusIntegration\"
FileSource = Folder & "excel.xlsx"

'This will return "W:\BusIntegration\excel.xlsx"
```

EDIT: As @BigBen said, if it is that you can't access the directory at all even in Windows Explorer then you absolutely need to have rights to access this before the code will work

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following code snippet in the past and it worked on a standalone computer - I do not think it would work on a remote network ….

```
'Piece of code to give the script administrator privileges
On Error Resume Next
If Not wScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate") Then
  CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute wScript.FullName, wScript.ScriptFullName & " /elevate", "", "runas", 1
  wScript.Quit
End If

'… your code 


On Error Goto 0
```